# On change toggle div each column has same name div and select option

Tags: jquery

How I can show/hide div on selection based.

I have select option where default is Yes and second option is No.

If selected Yes it should show div and if selected No it should hide div.

But I have grid where is 7 options with ID.

What I've tried already:

```
$(function () {
    $('#multiple_booking option:selected').each(function() {
        $(this).show(0).on('change', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).next('#show_max_booking').slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

My form:

```
<div class="col-sm">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>@lang('modules.settings.allowMultipleBooking')</label>
        <select name="multiple_booking" id="multiple_booking" class="form-control">
            <option value="yes">@lang('app.yes')</option>
            <option value="no">@lang('app.no')</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="show_max_booking">
        <label for="max_booking">@lang('modules.settings.maxBookingAllowed') <span class="text-info">( @lang('modules.settings.maxBookingAllowedInfo') )</span></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="max_booking" id="max_booking" value="0" step="1" min="0">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>@lang('modules.settings.allowMultipleBooking')</label>
        <select name="multiple_booking" id="multiple_booking" class="form-control">
            <option value="yes">@lang('app.yes')</option>
            <option value="no">@lang('app.no')</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="show_max_booking">
        <label for="max_booking">@lang('modules.settings.maxBookingAllowed') <span class="text-info">( @lang('modules.settings.maxBookingAllowedInfo') )</span></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="max_booking" id="max_booking" value="0" step="1" min="0">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>@lang('modules.settings.allowMultipleBooking')</label>
        <select name="multiple_booking" id="multiple_booking" class="form-control">
            <option value="yes">@lang('app.yes')</option>
            <option value="no">@lang('app.no')</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="show_max_booking">
        <label for="max_booking">@lang('modules.settings.maxBookingAllowed') <span class="text-info">( @lang('modules.settings.maxBookingAllowedInfo') )</span></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="max_booking" id="max_booking" value="0" step="1" min="0">
    </div>
</div>
....
```

Comment: The value of the id attribute must be unique within the HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use same id for more elements.

You can add class `multiple_booking` to the selects and some unique id, eg. `id="show_max_booking_0"` (1,2,3,...) to the divs you want to show/hide. Also add `data-toggle="show_max_booking_0"` to the select to let js know, which div should it toggle.

```
<div class="col-sm">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>@lang('modules.settings.allowMultipleBooking')</label>
        <select name="multiple_booking[]" class="form-control multiple_booking" data-toggle="show_max_booking_0">
            <option value="yes">@lang('app.yes')</option>
            <option value="no">@lang('app.no')</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="show_max_booking_0">
        <label for="max_booking">@lang('modules.settings.maxBookingAllowed') <span class="text-info">( @lang('modules.settings.maxBookingAllowedInfo') )</span></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="max_booking" id="max_booking" value="0" step="1" min="0">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then in jquery:

```
//will work only when "Yes" is default, otherwise you need to check value of select
$(function () {
    $('.multiple_booking').on('change', function() {
        $('#'+$(this).data('toggle')).slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```